# Bulk download images from Google image search (to disk)?

Tags: google-chrome, images

I have a project for my daughter, I want to get her images of animals.  We can get a lot of images from Google images, but I don't want to click save hundreds of times.

How could I shorten or automate the process of downloading the pictures?  I have tried a few plugins, but they download the thumbnail that is present on the Google Images page. I would like to download the actual full size pictures.

Comment: Does it need to be from google images? Or are you JUST trying to get a bunch of pictures of animals?

Comment: [Here](http://lifehacker.com/239561/geek-to-live--supercharge-your-firefox-downloads-with-downthemall) is a tutorial on how to bulk download the images in flicker using DownThemAll, but I do not know how to apply it in your case. Posting it here in the hope that it might be usefull to you(?)

Comment: Nope, does not have to be google images.  Thanks!

Comment: See [MultiImageDownloader (Revisited) 2.1](http://www.freewarefiles.com/MultiImageDownloader_program_55357.html).

Answer (score 0):

A [search](https://search.yahoo.com/yhs/search?p=crawler+to+download+images&ei=UTF-8&hspart=mozilla&hsimp=yhs-002) of "crawler to download images" shows quite a few programs that seem to accomplish a task.

I'm not sure if they would work on google images (I'm not well informed on the intricacies of crawlers), but I know crawlers work on sites like reddit (not recommending you use that particular site, just giving an example). So if you are just looking to download lots of pictures, not specifically from google, then a crawler might work fairly well.

Comment: This does not really answer the author's question.  Linking to a google search is fine, provided, you give a specific solution to the problem.  Most of your answer seems to be commetary.

Comment: @Ramhound While normally I would bow to your experience, in this case I disagree. The question was looking for a solution (the original asked for a software recommendation, but when put in scope) to downloading a large amount of pictures. My solution was the use of a crawler program, and linked to the Google search that provided me with results. I don't want to make software recommendations, so I just made a general program suggestion. I believe that such a suggestion is indeed an answer to the author's question. However, your experience is greater than mine, so feel free to correct me.

Comment: You made no specific recomendations though.  You just linked to a Yahoo search result.

Comment: @Ramhound I was under the impression that, in general, specific recommendations (specific piece of software, etc.) were less desirable for the same reason that just posting links isn't desirable: If the specific suggestion is changed, removed, etc., then future users who have the same question are out of luck. I would think this would be especially true with a small piece of software like a crawler. I thought that general suggestions were more desirable as they had a larger effect than just the original author of the question. Apologies if this thought process was mistaken.

Comment: You can make software recomendations, if the solution to the problem, warrants it.  You just have to provide more then "use this product" as an answer.  Besides this can be done without third-party software but use a script, which would be helpful, provided it was more then a link answer ( like the answer that did that ) but was deleted likely by the author or the community.

Comment: @MattWalck:  The objective of an answer is to explain how to accomplish a solution (and to do that here rather than provide a link to the explanation).  If you can also teach why it works, that's even better.  Pointing the reader in the right direction and they have to figure out how to accomplish the result is really a comment rather than an answer.  Just providing a link to a specific tool is in that category.  Mentioning a class of tools, so the reader has to first find a specific tool is even further removed from an answer.

Comment: As Ramhound said, there's nothing wrong with a software rec in an answer if it's warranted and the answer meets certain standards.  Good discussion and guidance on software recs: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers

Answer (score 0):

If you have an OS X, check out CocoData. The user interface has a regular expression query box that makes it easy to download image URL links (even from Google images).

[image: example picture]

The following Python 3 code can be used to download these images.

```
import urllib.request
file = open("/Users/rohankotwani/Downloads/animals.txt").read().split("\n")
image_folder_location = "/Users/rohankotwani/Downloads/Animals/image"
i=0
for link in file:
    f = open(image_folder_location+str(i)+'.jpg','wb')
    f.write(urllib.request.urlopen(link).read())
    f.close()
    i=i+1
```